# Firefox Javascript regex to get array of numbers within square brackets but excluding brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox, lookbehind

**Sample input**

```
var abc = "blah blah [abc] , [123] [ab12], [456] [cdef] 789 ghi000 "
```

**Expected output**

```
["123", "456"]
```

I am trying to write regex that should match only the numbers within the square brackets and return an array of those numbers (excluding the []).

The regex that I tried used lookbehind so it worked from Chrome but failed for firefox. I found later that lookbehind is not yet supported in firefox (Visit https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1225665).

```
abc.match(/(?<=\[)(\d+)/g);
```

I get the expected output on Chrome 76:

```
["123", "456"]
```

but I get error on Firefox 68:

```
SyntaxError: invalid regexp group
```

How can I write a regex that works on both and generate expected result.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `match` and `map`

```js
var abc = "blah blah [abc] , [123] [ab12], [456] [cdef] 789 ghi000 "

let output = abc.match(/\[\d+\]/g).map(m=>m.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/g, "$1"))

console.log(output)
```

Or you can use `exec`

```js
var regex1 = /\[(\d+)\]/g
var str1 = "blah blah [abc] , [123] [ab12], [456] [cdef] 789 ghi000 "
var array1;

while ((array1 = regex1.exec(str1)) !== null) {
  console.log(`Found ${array1[1]}`);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use capturing groups, e.g.:

```
var abc = "blah blah [abc] , [123] [ab12], [456] [cdef] 789 ghi000 ";
Array.from(abc.matchAll(/\[(\d+)\]/g)).map(m => m[1])
```

[matchAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) *(note the browser compatibility)* finds every occurrence of `[NNN]` and captures the digits inside the square brackets as `match[1]`.

`Array.from()` converts the iterator returned from `matchAll` to an array, which can then be processed to extract the capture.

Comment: thanks for your solution, it definitely works, however due to browser compatibility (as you also mentioned) I will refrain from using matchAll now.

Comment: Sure, that doesn't change the main idea of using the capturing groups. You just have to [use RegExp's exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll#Regexp.exec()_and_matchAll()) in a loop instead of my one-liner.